# Jquery addition subtraction through checkbox not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am  taking value of input .and modifying it through check box.Addition working on it and subtraction also  ,if i display response in span working perfectly ,but if i display response in same input box not working

Here is a Snippet:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  function displayVals() {
    calcUsage();
    var singleValues = $("#more").val();
    $("#span").html("<b>more addons:</b> " +
      singleValues + ' QR');
  }
  var $cbs = $('input[name="ch1"]');

  function calcUsage() {
    var total = $("#more").val();
    $cbs.each(function() {
      if (this.checked)
        total = parseInt(total) + parseInt(this.value);
    });

    var amt = $("#total_amt").val();
    var grand_total = parseInt(total) + parseInt(amt);
    $("#usertotal").text(grand_total);

  }

  $("select").change(displayVals);
  displayVals();
  //For  checkboxes

  $cbs.click(calcUsage);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="container">
  <h1>Add-ons</h1>
  <input type="checkbox" name="ch1" value="10" id="qr1" />Add-on Number 1 - 10 QR
  <br />
  <input type="checkbox" name="ch1" value="20" id="qr1" />Add-on Number 2 - 20 QR
  <br />
  <input type="checkbox" name="ch1" value="40" id="qr1" />Add-on Number 3 - 40 QR
  <br />
  <input type="checkbox" name="ch1" value="60" id="qr1" />Add-on Number 4 - 60 QR
  <br />
</div>

<div>I want more add-ons
  <select id="more" name="more" style="display:none">
    <option value="0">0</option>
    <option value="30">1</option>
    <option value="50">2</option>
    <option value="100">3</option>
  </select>
  <span id="span"></span>
  User total usage: <span id="usertotal"> </span>

  <br>
  <input type="text" name="total" id="total_amt" value="400" />
  <div id="ad">
    <div id="ad"></div>
```

Comment: Better to use the snippet feature.

Comment: Looks okay for me if I run that. What's the problem now?

Comment: yes pravin , can u help me

Comment: i want the result in input box

Comment: That's **Praveen**, not anything else! Ah!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not putting assigning to the input:

```
$("#usertotal").text(grand_total);
$("#total_amt").val(grand_total);
```

**Snippet**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var initVal = $("#more").val();
  function displayVals() {
    calcUsage();
    var singleValues = parseInt(initVal);
    $("#span").html("<b>more addons:</b> " +
      singleValues + ' QR');
  }
  var $cbs = $('input[name="ch1"]');

  function calcUsage() {
    var total = 400;
    $cbs.each(function() {
      if (this.checked)
        total = parseInt(total) + parseInt(this.value);
    });

    var amt = initVal;
    var grand_total = parseInt(total) + parseInt(amt);
    $("#usertotal").text(grand_total);
    $("#total_amt").val(grand_total);

  }

  $("select").change(displayVals);
  displayVals();
  //For  checkboxes

  $cbs.click(calcUsage);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="container">
  <h1>Add-ons</h1>
  <input type="checkbox" name="ch1" value="10" id="qr1" />Add-on Number 1 - 10 QR
  <br />
  <input type="checkbox" name="ch1" value="20" id="qr1" />Add-on Number 2 - 20 QR
  <br />
  <input type="checkbox" name="ch1" value="40" id="qr1" />Add-on Number 3 - 40 QR
  <br />
  <input type="checkbox" name="ch1" value="60" id="qr1" />Add-on Number 4 - 60 QR
  <br />
</div>

<div>I want more add-ons
  <select id="more" name="more" style="display:none">
    <option value="0">0</option>
    <option value="30">1</option>
    <option value="50">2</option>
    <option value="100">3</option>
  </select>
  <span id="span"></span>
  User total usage: <span id="usertotal"> </span>

  <br>
  <input type="text" name="total" id="total_amt" value="400" />
  <div id="ad">
    <div id="ad"></div>
```

Comment: if we uncheck result is not subtracting